# Record customer log to database by Spring boot filter

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I got a Spring boot website.

And now, I want to create a filter to record user behavior to the database.

For example, Mary uses the API "/operate/saveMoney" to save 800 dollars to her bank account.

Spring boot filter catches the request then records the behavior to the database.

Database has a table to record the behavior like: "Mary", "/operate/saveMoney", "save 800 dollars", "Action success"

I want to record all operation via API, is it possible by filter?

If yes, can you give me some tips or a keyword?

If not, does it have another way to record it?

Thank you for watching and help~

Comment: Looks like Spring AOP could serve this purpose. It can intercept every times there is a request, then save that request information to database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use swagger as a log aspect, by adding @Log, @ApiOperation annotation to get the parameters carried in the annotation, so that you can get the request URL, input parameters, IP, output parameters and other parameters, which can be saved to the log table or log file. Main reference tools:

```html
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
```